# Create new artboard in column

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I have a minor issue with adding new artboards so that they line up in a column. 
In older versions of illustrator, as I recall, new artboards where added beneath the active one. Now they end up to the right. Is there a way to change where the new artboard automatically end up? I want a quick way to make new artboards perfectly aligned in a column, so please no tips on manually dragging artboards, nor aligning in the artboard panel.

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of rectangle objects arranged however you like, then select them all and convert them to artboards via **Object > Artboards > Convert to Artboards**.

Comment: Great answer, I wouldn't have thought of that. The simple things...

Comment: Pro tip: When converting multiple shapes to artboards, Illustrator numbers them according to their front-to-back hierarchy.